# Overlap of two images is switched

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, dem, overlapping-features

I try to find a way to create DEM model for two overlapping images from different sources. The upper image has transparency of 50% and as you can see they don't quite overlap correctly. The projections are adjusted correctly (EPSG:3006 - SWEREF99 TM), but they still look this way.

Why is this happening?

I am new to QGIS and GIS in general.

[image: overlapping images]

Comment: How did you adjust the projections?

Comment: I tried both in properties (Set source CRS) and Raster->Projections->Warp.. but neither helped - the image remained the same

Comment: Do not use `Set source CRS`. This does not reproject your raster. Reset it to its original projection. `Warp` should actually do it then. If not, whats the source of your raster?

Comment: One image is from DigitalGlobe and another one from Lantmaterialet (Orthophoto) - https://www.lantmateriet.se/en/maps-and-geographic-information/geodataprodukter/ortofoto/ - I used QGIS to merge several photos from the last one